# Applying background color to div after append method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm trying to create a dynamic color *bookmarker* just to practice jQuery, however, I'm having an issue using the append method to make a new div and applying a CSS background method to apply the text of the div (the input) as the color of the individual div. My problem is not getting the background color applied. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong or why my `.css()` method isn't working.

```
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

colorIn.keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var inVal = colorIn.val();
    var color = $(".color");
    colorIn.val("");
    function addBackColor() { 
        $("this").css('background-color', $(this).text())
    };
    var addDiv = $('<div onload="addBackColor()">' +inVal+ '</div>').addClass("color");
    matDes.append(addDiv);
  }
});
```

I've also made a pen for it:
http://codepen.io/Aricha03/pen/KzqXmr

Comment: `addBackColor` is local to the keypress handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codepen there is typo

```
 $(this).css('backgound-color', 'backColor');
```

It should be `background-color` & not `backgound-color` . Also backColor is a variable & it is not a `string`

```
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

colorIn.keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which ===13){
        var newDiv = colorIn.val();
        colorIn.val("");
        matDes.append('<div class="color">' + newDiv + '</div>');
        var color = $(".color");
            console.log(color);
        color.each(function(){
            var backColor = $(this).text();
                    console.log(backColor);
            $(this).css('background-color', backColor); // I changed here

        });        
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7wc948b7/1/)

Comment: Oh boy do I feel like a dummy. Damn typos. Thanks so much, that about solves that.

Answer (score 0):

addBackColor is local function for keypress event, you have to move it outside of keypress event

```
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

function addBackColor(element) { 
    $(element).css('background-color', $(element).text())
};

colorIn.keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var inVal = colorIn.val();
    var color = $(".color");
    colorIn.val("");

    var addDiv = $('<div onload="addBackColor(this)">' +inVal+ '</div>').addClass("color");
    matDes.append(addDiv);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes for the `color` value

```
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

colorIn.keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which ===13){
        var newDiv = colorIn.val();
        colorIn.val("");
        matDes.append('<div class="color">' + newDiv + '</div>');
        var color = $(".color");
        color.each(function(){
            var backColor = $(this).text();
            $(this).css('background-color', backColor);  //I removed quotes for the backcolor and r missing in background color
                        alert(backColor);
        });        
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried without the quotes as well. If you test it out on my pen it still doesn't work. I need the newly created div to have the background color of the color hex text

Comment: I also tested in your pen..its work fine thats why i posted the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.css()` to set the style

```js
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

colorIn.keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var inVal = colorIn.val();
    var color = $(".color");
    colorIn.val("");

    var addDiv = $('<div/>', {
      text: inVal
    }).css({
      'background-color': inVal
    }).addClass("color");
    matDes.append(addDiv);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="material-design">
</div>
<input type="text" id="materialColorInput" class="colorInput">
<!--
Material Design
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
Purple
Pink
Black
White

Material Design Color Combo
Aurora
Space
Jungle
Japan
China

Vintage
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
Purple
Pink
Black
White
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in CodePen

```
var colorIn = $("#materialColorInput");
var matDes = $(".material-design");

colorIn.on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var inVal = colorIn.val();
    var color = $(".color");
    var backColor = colorIn.val();
    var addDiv = $('<div>' +inVal+ '</div>').addClass("color").attr('style','background-color: ' + backColor);
    matDes.append(addDiv);
    colorIn.val("");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code ...Please check the Edited Pen

```
colorIn.keypress(function(event){
if(event.which ===13){
    var newDiv = colorIn.val();
    colorIn.val("");
    matDes.append('<div class="color">' + newDiv + '</div>');
    var color = $(".color");
    color.each(function(){
        var backColor = $(this).text();
        $(this).css("background-color", backColor);
                    console.log(backColor);
    });        
}
```

});

Please check the  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqwvKG?editors=1011